# SQL Server and MongoDB comparison?

Tags: sql-server, performance, mongodb

I was trying to compare and see if my database in SQL Server can be migrated to MongoDB for better performance. The database is pretty much schema less with lot of inserts and updates over the columns. Table is something like this (Primary key as Product_ID)

ProductID   Part1 Part2 Part3 ... so on with lot of columns upto 70

So far I did not find any significant performance improvement with MongoDB. Both perform almost at same speed (Some times SQL Server jumps up and performs more updates). I am properly indexing the MongoDB database over ProductID which is the one I look while updating.

Is this type of database not suitable for taking advantage of MongoDB performance over SQL Server ?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome!

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are lots of potential concerns here.

> I am properly indexing the MongoDB database over ProductID which is the one I look while updating.

First thing to note is that Mongo uses an `_id` field for internal IDs. Put differently, Mongo automatically has an auto-increment ID (similar to a GUID, but smaller). The `_id` field automatically gets an index, so if you index on `ProductID` you may have two indexes where only one is necessary.

If you're using the NoRM driver, please look up on the usage patterns for "making your own IDs".

> The database is pretty much schema less with lot of inserts and updates over the columns. Table is something like this... ProductID Part1 Part2 Part3

This concept of "parts" should perform fast and require a smaller footprint than SQL server. Notice that each document stores both the field name and the value. So if you have field names of `p1` instead of `Part1`, you will use less space and get to keep more records in RAM.

> So far I did not find any significant performance improvement with MongoDB...

This is where you have to go into details about your testing methodologies. How many documents. how much total space, how much RAM on the machine, how are you testing, etc?

Without more details it's simply not possible to provide specific guidance.

Comment: Hi Gates, Thanks for your insights. I am still not sure how to use the _id indexes when I need to use ProductID for updates aswell as future queries over the database. Actually the field names are pretty small only 3 to 4 letters. Right now I did not test it over machine with high resources. I will try it in test machines where I have like 16 gb ram and 3.2 gigs processor. Let me see how it goes and will get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I can re-phrase this. By default, every document created in MongoDB has a MongoID created for it. This MongoID is stored in the `_id` field. By default this `_id` field is indexed. This field is basically an auto-increment primary key (but more sophisticated). You have a `ProductID` field which was *probably* an auto-increment primary key. If you build an index on `ProductID`, you now have two indexes, but you'll only ever use one them. So instead of having a `MongoID` *and* `ProductID`, you can over-write `_id` with your `ProductID` and save on indexes (which will be faster).

Answer (score 2):

Common practice is to use "big" object in MongoDb. it is need for refuse to use any join.
For example: use UserDocument that already have list of self orders and etc.
I have experience in migrate from SQl to MongoDb.And i improve my system in several times.
In the SQL Server we has over 100 tables, and now in mongo i have not more then 20.

Comment: Could you give any resources for big object? I am using NoRM driver with C# for testing this. Also in future I would need full text search over the database.

Comment: mongoDb is support full text search.You can read about it in doc . And about big objects - i mean try to join object in one as it impossible.For example we join user with user rating, user invoice, and etc. and We got several root documents

Comment: example:  UserDocument{    #base fields. public List<InvoiceDocument> Invoices { get; set;} public LedgerBookDocument LedgerBook { get; set;}}